# Is there a definitive naming convention for methods returning IAsyncEnumerable?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

After C# 5 introduced the `async` and `await` model for asynchronous programming, the C# community arrived at a naming convention to add an "Async" suffix to methods returning an awaitable type, like this:

```
interface Foo
{
   Task BarAsync();
}
```

Many static code analyzers (both Roslyn-based and non-Roslyn-based) have since been written to depend on this naming convention when detecting code smell around asynchronous programming.

Now that C# 8 has introduced the concept of asynchronous enumerables, which themselves are not awaitable but can be used in conjunction with `await foreach`, there seems to be two options for naming methods returning `IAsyncEnumerable`:

```
interface Foo
{
    // No "Async" suffix, indicating that the return value is not awaitable.
    IAsyncEnumerable<T> Bar<T>();
}
```

or

```
interface Foo
{
    // With "Async" suffix, indicating that the overall logic is asynchronous.
    IAsyncEnumerable<T> BarAsync<T>();
}
```

Has there been a definitive naming convention guideline (from the C# language team, the .NET Foundation, or other authorities) regarding the options above, like how the C# 5 naming convention was unambiguously standardized and not left to opinion-based judgement of programmers?

Comment: The option 2 sounds correct here, since your run this code asynchronously (mark method as `async` and use `await` inside), and [msdn sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/generate-consume-asynchronous-stream#convert-to-async-streams) shows the same

Comment: In response to the closure of the question, I have edited the question to ask whether a definitive naming convention exists, and to give example of how a definitive naming convention in C#5 resulted in developments in static code analysis. Therefore having C#8 follow that pattern will result in measurable code quality improvements beyond opinion-based coding preferences.

Comment: .NET Core itself uses the `Async` suffix for methods that return `IAsyncEnumerable`, eg [ChannelReader.ReadAllAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1.readallasync?view=netcore-3.1). In other cases, eg in EF Core, `AsAsyncEnumerable()` is used which is already clear

Comment: Naming guidelines exist to make it easier for humans to understand the code. If the code's purpose isn't clear, add the suffix.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no better guideline than what the .NET teams *already* do :

- [ChannelReader.ReadAllAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1.readallasync?view=netcore-3.1) returns an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`
- In EF Core 3, results are returned as an `IAsyncEnumerable` by calling [AsAsyncEnumerable()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.asasyncenumerable?view=efcore-3.1)
- In System.Linq.Async, [ToAsyncEnumerable()](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/master/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/Operators/ToAsyncEnumerable.cs) converts IEnumerables, Tasks and Observables into `IAsyncEnumerable`s
- All other operators in `System.Linq.Async` retain their names. There's no `SelectAsync` or `SelectAsAsyncEnumerable`, just `Select`.

In all cases, it's clear what the result of the method is. In all cases, the results of the method need to be awaited with `await foreach` before they can be used.

So the *real* guideline remains the same - *ensure the name makes the behavior clear*:

- When the name is already clear, eg with `AsAsyncEnumerable()` or `ToAsyncEnumerable()`, there's no need to add any suffix.
- In other cases, add the `Async` suffix so *developers* know they need to `await foreach` the result.

---

The code analyzers and generators don't really care about the names of methods, they detect smells by inspecting the code itself. A code analyzer will tell you that you forgot to await a Task or `await foreach` an `IAsyncEnumerable` no matter how you call the methods and the variables. A generator can simply use reflection to check for `IAsyncEnumerable` and emit `await foreach`

It's the *style* analyzers that check names. Their job is to ensure the code uses a consistent style so *developers* can understand the code. The style analyzer will tell you that a method doesn't follow the style you chose. That style may be the team's or a commonly accepted style guide.

And of course, everyone knows the common prefix for private instance fields is `_` :)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the `ChannelReader.ReadAllAsync` example. Since this comes straight from the .NET team, it's hard to go wrong following suit.

Comment: Analyzer packages often come with a mix bag of style and non-style analyzers. For example, the [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.Analyzers](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/tree/master/src/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.Analyzers) package has a style analyzer that checks naming convention (VSTHRD200) and a non-style analyzer that detect hazardous situations that can potentially lead to deadlock (VSTHRD111). To reference the package to take advantage of VSTHRD111, a project would also end up with VSTHRD200.

Answer (score 3):

It’s not an async method, so the name shouldn’t end in ‘Async’.  That method suffix is a convention to make it obvious that the method should be awaited, or the result handled as a Task.

I think a normal collection-returning name is appropriate.  GetFoos(), or similar.

Comment: All those are arguments *for* using the `Async` suffix. The suffix is used in .NET Core itself:  [ChannelReader.ReadAllAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1.readallasync?view=netcore-3.1) returns an IAsyncEnumerable. An `IAsyncEnumerable` has to be used with `await foreach`, so the suffix makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

The answer, per the .Net team, seems to be that methods returning IAsyncEnumerable<> ought to end in “Async”.

Stephen Toub, one of the .Net runtime superstars, stated so for public APIs for C# streams, on this GitHub issue:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27547#issuecomment-478384285

> Yes [the method names will end in “Async”]. The most common consumption will be via await foreach, and it
> serves as a similar visual indicator of where asynchrony is involved,
> allows for differentiation from sync enumerables, etc.

Answer (score 0):

*Async* suffix and even keyword `async` is just boilerplate, it is meaningless other than some backward compatability arguments. C# has all information to distinct those functions just like it distincts `yield` in methods which return `IEnumerable`, as you know you don't need to add anything like `enumerable` or some other keyword on such methods.

You need to add *Async* suffix just because C# will complain about overloads, so essentially those two are identical and they do same thing by all rules of polymorphism (if we are not taking human factor of intentially corrupting behavior into account):

```
public interface IMyContract
{
    Task<int> Add(int a, int b);
    int Add(int a, int b);
}
```

But you can't write it like this because compilator will complain. But, hey! It will swallow this one monstrosity:

```
public interface IMyContract : IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable<long>
{
}
```

and even this:

```
public interface IMyContractAsync
{
    Task<int> Add(int a, int b);
}

public interface IMyContract : IMyContractAsync
{
    int Add(int a, int b);
}
```

So this is it. You add *Async* just to stop compiler to complain. Not to clarify things. Not to make them better. If there is no complain - no reason to add it, so in your case I will avoid this, unless it becomes `Task<IAsyncEnumerable>`.

**PS:** Just for better of understanding of entire picture here - if sometime in future someone add in C# quantum-computer method extensions (fantazy, huh) which will operate in different paradigm, we probably will need another suffix like *Quant* or something, because C# will complain otherwise. It will be exact same method but it will do it's work another way. Just like polymorphism do. Just like interfaces do.

Comment: Sorry, but I feel I disagree, it's not really different approach of doing same thing - it;s more - it is expected to be called differently, and result to be collected differently. That is the most difference between async and non-async. I strongly believe adding the async is for clarity. I think this is also Microsoft's recommendation.

Comment: Yeah, I agree but disagree. Just like in List you have simple Sort function and not "QuickSort", "RadixSort", "BubbleSort", "MixOfSorts". They are different, used by scope but obviously doesn't need clarification other than for debugging purposes (I mean you only care for them when they make an impact on performance/resources). In this case DoThing and DoThingAsync is in same situation than any other templated algorithm, they don't need clarification, it is either supported or not, and usefull only for debugging.

Comment: Thats different, async means - heu caller make sure you handle this corrently. Fact of retirning Task is not enough to say that method is truly Async. Caller must know to await or use GetAwaiter().GetResilt() to get same oitput. That is different not how the things are done inside.

Comment: This is entirely purpose of code analyzers and compilator. IntellySense can easily point this out for you, no need to use developers brains for highlighting or even banishing using of sync method over async one in asynchronous code. From my experience when using Async I rarelly need to use GetResult(), but I frequently need to pollute entire code-base with Async.

Comment: As someone marked that - it is opinion. We can keep believe in what we believe and be happy :)

Comment: Yeah, this sucks =)